# Automatic installation for GUI with out manual interaction

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

I want to install one GUI application without user intercation. The installation will ask some inputs from the installer while installing.  So I want to automate it completely.

The OS which I am using is : WinXP and Win7
Can any one please help me out on this.

Comment: Please keep in mind that we're not mind readers. This would be like going to an auto garage and saying "I want to make my car better. How can I make my car better?" - It's incomplete and doesn't have any detail. You need to help us help you.

Answer (score 1):

Almost all software can be installed silently. If it's an MSI file, then it *has* be be able to be installed silently, per the spec (though some vendors do dumb things that make this not actually work).

If you're working with an MSI file, just do `msiexec /i <path to the file> /qb!` if you want no user interaction, but you want a progress bar to show. If you want it completely silent, replace `/qb!` with `/q`.

If you're working with software that isn't installed from an MSI, then you need to **read the manual** for it. It will tell you if a silent installation is possible.